# Kate External Tools Plugin

Tags: compiling, plugins, kate

I have installed Kate Editor (with KWrite, which installs some plugins) and I have just realized that the *Kate External Tools* plugin is missing since version 4.8.
I really need this plugin, and if anyone could show me where to find an older Kate version or even the plugin itself I would really appreciate that.

EDIT: By the way, I have found in [this](https://bitbucket.org/ZaWertun/kate-plugin-externaltools) webpage the plugin, but (my Linux level is average) I am not able to install it: when I get to the `make` command, I get the following error:

`[ 88%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/kateexternaltoolsplugin.dir/kate_externaltools_plugin.o
In file included from /home/nybble/kate-plugin-externaltools/kate_externaltools_plugin.cpp:3:0:
/home/nybble/kate-plugin-externaltools/kate_externaltools_plugin.h:6:25: fatal error: kate/plugin.h: No such file or directory
 #include <kate/plugin.h>
                         ^
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/kateexternaltoolsplugin.dir/build.make:179: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/kateexternaltoolsplugin.dir/kate_externaltools_plugin.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/kateexternaltoolsplugin.dir/kate_externaltools_plugin.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:60: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/kateexternaltoolsplugin.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/kateexternaltoolsplugin.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2`

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please [edit] and post the exact error messages.

Comment: It's edited now :)